# How to create a TreeView in Android Xamarin?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

In listview, I want :

Categorya

```
 Category1
     Item1
     Item2
```

Categoryb

```
 Category1
     Item1
     Item2
```

[image]
As picture that just have 1 level. But I want to have three level.
How to do that? Expandable/Collapsible ListView in xamarin

Comment: Are you sure you want this? I can't imagine it being a good user experience on a touch device

Comment: I'm just study how to create it .

Answer (score 0):

You can use an `ExpandableListView` which should match exactly what you've posted as a screenshot.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html

Java tutorial - http://www.androidhive.info/2013/07/android-expandable-list-view-tutorial/ (Should be fairly simple to convert the Java -> C#)